# Why does changing the curve radius not produce smooth transitions when using Curve to Mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have a curve here where the curve points are given different values for *Radius*.

With these radii I want to control the extrusion of the curve when using `Curve to Mesh`, so that the mesh gets thicker or thinner.

This works very well, however I don't get smooth transitions but wherever I use different values for *Radius*, hard corners appear in the mesh that I wouldn't expect.

[image]

Why is this? How can I smooth the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Curve to Mesh` node uses the lineary interpolated values between the points, so a change in the radius from $0 - 1 - 0$, for example, will be displayed with a hard edge.

It is also very difficult to smooth the mesh afterwards, so you would have to change the radius along the curve points beforehand.

Exactly for such purposes the node [Blur Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/blur_attribute.html) is available since version **3.5+**.

This node smooths the values between a specified number (*Iterations*) of neighboring elements with a specified strength (*Weight*):

[image]

Depending on the nature of your curve, however, you would have to make sure that it has enough points at all, which is why you would usually have to give the curve a higher resolution with `Resample Curve`, `Subdivide Curve` and/or `Set Resolution`.

This is important because the number of points or the resolution of the curve always works in combination with the value for *Iterations*, because with this you control how many neighboring elements/points are used for smoothing:

[image]
<sub>(Changing *Iterations* from 0 - 250 - 0)</sub>

---

By the way, `Blur Attribute` is a pretty ingenious node, and is often underestimated or ignored.

With it you can also smooth the positions of points, for example:

[image]
[image]

Also in combination with a Noise this node can be very helpful and achieve interesting results.

**Always note, however:**
With many elements and a high iteration value this node also needs a lot of computing power!
Therefore try to choose the use consciously, use the node sparingly and only as high iteration values as absolutely needed.

---

From the comments:

- Of course, you could also process the radii with a `Map Range` node (Set to *Smooth Step* or *Smoother Step*). However, radii with values higher than $1$ (even if they are changed with *From Max* and *To Max*) cannot be processed correctly then because this also changes the interpolation. The result is still nice in most cases.
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147181/discussion-on-answer-by-quellenform-why-does-changing-the-curve-radius-not-produ); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.